# Does the Machine Gun also affect the player using it?

Tags: shadow-hunters

The description of the Machine Gun card says: "Your attack will affect all characters in your attack range."

Does this mean that the player himself gets damaged as well? That wouldn't make much sense logically from a machine gun, but the rules seem pretty clear about it.

Comment: Pretty sure the Machine Gun doesn't affect the player using it, but reading the manual I don't see any rules that say you can't attack yourself.

Comment: Also note that the entire section in the rules is called "Attack **other** player(s)", though from then on it talks about attacking "a" player. I also think you don't shoot yourself but can't prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the machine gun does not attack you as well. When you attack you can only attack other players and it specifies that in the rules. The only time you can do damage to yourself is on weird woods and when a card says you can target any player with damage.

The problem with being able to damage yourself with the machine gun is that there are roles that want to die first and being able to damage yourself like that would make it to easy to win.

[Rules](http://www.zmangames.com/uploads/4/7/1/7/47170931/en-shadowhunter-rules-2015.pdf)

> Attack other player(s)